# How do i get the current date in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How do you get the current date (not time) in C# ?

Example:

```
19/03/2011
```

[Edit] 
 I got the solution. thanks for  answering... :)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; 

string sDate = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: I got the solution. thanks for  answering... :)
`DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
 string sDate = dt.ToShortDateString();`

Comment: i prefer more ToString("d") then ToShortDateString() cause ToString() has overload which can optionaly receive culture info, ToShortDateString is always bound to Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

Answer (score 19):

Use [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx):

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
```

Answer (score 7):

`System.DateTime.Now.Date` will get the date part only. It actually gives you the date at midnight.